# NodeJS Multiparty file upload to Azure and a text field

Tags: node.js, azure, multipartform-data, multiparty

I need to verify that a mongodb document exists before continuing with Azure file upload.

The form consists of a file and a text field, the logic that is needed is the following:

1. Form submission
2. Get the text field
3. Search in mongodb for a document with the text field data
4. If the item exist continue with file upload to Azure else return
5. File upload to Azure
6. Save the URL to the file in the same MongoDB document that was found in

The problem I'm facing is that I can't touch field data in form.on('part') and can't get it to work with using form.parse first. 
This is my code, I'm willing to change libraries and do whatever it takes to get it working.

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var formField = "";
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  formField = fields.fieldinform[0];
});
console.log(formField); //empty async?

model
  .findOne({ name: formField })
  .then(obj => {
    form.on("part", function(part) {

      if (!part.filename) return;


      var size = part.byteCount;
      var name = part.filename;
      var container = "test";

      blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(
        container,
        name,
        part,
        size,
        function(error) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("failed");
          }
        }
      );
    });
  })
  .catch(e => {
    //do not continue
  });
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and not coming up with a proper answer I decided to go with jquery that changed the action URL of the form to /upload/textintextfield before submission and then grab that with req.params.textfield in node.

```
<script>
$('#fileUploadForm').submit(function() {
$('#fileUploadForm').attr('action', '/upload/addvideo/' + $('#textfield').val())
return true; 
});
</script>
```